# Не отображаются поля ACF в таксономии / начинают отображаться везде

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Имеется поле в плагине ACF. Но с выводом целая беда.

Структура примерно такая
I
1,2,3
II
4,5,6

```
<?php echo get_field( 'contactofman'); ?>
```

где contactofman - имя поля
не выводит ничего. Аналогичный код работает с обычными постами, страницами, но не с таксономиями.
добавляем костыль с tag_id, который по идее должен бы указать, где это поле искать.

```
 <?php echo get_field( 'contactofman', "cat_products_168"); ?>
```

где "cat_products" - имя категории; 168 - tag_id одной из категории.

Выводит содержание поля во все категории, даже если заполнено оно только в одной из категорий.
К примеру, поле заполняется при редактировании категории 1, а выводится в I, 1,2,3, II и далее.

Вопрос банальный - как привязать вывод содержания конкретного поля "1х" в категорию "1", а поля "Iх" в категорию I.

Вывод изображения с поля для каждой из категорий работает:

```
<?php $previewLink = get_field('product_slider', $posts->ID)[0]['img']['sizes']['large']; ?>
```

Попробовал копирнуть способ определения:

```
<?php echo get_field( 'contactofman', $posts->ID)[0]; ?>
```

Ничего не выводит.

Документацию читал, форумы читал - проблема распространённая, но решения так и не нашёл.

Comment: для таксономии нужно, чтоб было get_field( 'field', "название-таксономии_айди"); cat_product - что это? почему для получения поля используете cat_products ?

Comment: Это название категории

Comment: cat_product и cat_products - отличаются. там должна быть таксономия

Comment: Всего лишь очепятка в посте, прошу прощения

Comment: честно отвратительно описано , чтоб как-то Вам помочь

Comment: Что не так? Какая информация требуется?
Ломаю голову третий день - не могу вывести простейшее значение поля. Просто отказывается работать.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно будет передать туда [queried object](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_queried_object), если я верно понял вашу проблему, таким образом:

$queried_object = get_queried_object();
the_field( “contactfoman”, $queried_object );

Comment: этот код сработает только на странице метки. для других типов страниц - он не функционален

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с предыдущим оратором ( Simon ). Все верно указано.

А в том случае, когда вы хотите вывести поле таксономии другой страницы вы должны проявить фантазию.

в цикле `$categories = get_categories($args);`

```
foreach($categories as $cat) {
  $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
                        $WP_Query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $cat_id));
                        $term = $WP_Query->get_queried_object();
                        $image = get_field('cat_img', $term);
}
```

Ну и как видно из примера вам нужен не id категории, а его term